# How can I import a .PYD module in IronPython?

Tags: import, ironpython, pyd

I'm trying to use a python package from IronPython.
Everything works fine if I import regular python modules.

But when I try to do the following:

```
import win32ui
```

I get:

```
No module named win32ui
```

I've hunted through the code in IronPython.Runtime.Importer and there's no mention of .pyd

Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check out [IronClad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) which is working to provide this support.  It may or may not work w/ your PYD of choice.

Answer (score 4):

[A .pyd file is a DLL.](http://pyfaq.infogami.com/is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll)  So unless IronPython (which is written in .net) can correctly load C DLLs written for CPython, you might be out of luck.

---

Update

In fact, [according to the IronPython FAQ](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=FAQ), you are unfortunately unable to import .pyd files:

> Q: How do I build and call into PYD libraries?
>
> A: IronPython does not support using PYDs built for CPython since they
>   leverage implementation details of CPython.  You can get a similar
>   effect for new "PYD"s you would like to implement by writing them in C#
>   or VB and building a DLL for .NET.