# how to set input and output parameters in arcobjects using c#, which call python script?

Tags: c#, python, arcgis, arcobjects, arcpy

I have written a python script to geoprocessing ArcGIS data and set the workspace, input and output parameters inside the python code as:

```
env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# input feature class 
inFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# output feature class
Transect_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
```

Since I am new to ArcObjects using c# in Visual Studio 2010, I am trying to use ArcMap Add-in to add a button into the ArcMap desktop. But I didn't know how to call this python script from c#, and get something like a textbox popup and ask the information about the input and output parameters path. Since I directly call the python, it didn't work with the `GetParameterAsText` command inside the python code.

I highly appreciate if someone there can help on this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which GP are you trying to use?  Are you trying to set a parameter or specify an 'out' parameter?

Comment: I am using arcpy in python 2.6 dealing with ArcMap 10 GP. I try to call my python code from Visual studio 2010 ADD-IN. So I add a button in the ArcMap 10 to run my python command. It didn't work. It seem that GetParameterAsText only work if you turn the python code into a tool in the ArcToolbox. So I didn't know how to set the input feature classes and/or output feature classes by calling Python code from c# in Visual Studio and resolve this problem. I wish I can explain more clear. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the .NET Developer Help at the Esri pages:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Consuming_a_geoprocessing_model_tool_in_NET/0001000001sw000000/

Work through it, and you should have learned how to call a geoprocessing tool from ArcMap. To do so, you have to make a toolbox containing your python script. This can be called with .NET code (see the walkthrough).

Note: Most of this basic development stuff is already well documented at the Esri pages, but sometimes hard to find ;-)

Answer (score 1):

ArcPy does not support [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/), it gives the error ”cannot load library arcgisscripting”. I believe the problem is that is that [IronPython does not support pyd files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228613/how-can-i-import-a-pyd-module-in-ironpython) which arcgisscripting contained within.

ESRI offer the following sample for [leveraging ArcPy in .net](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Leveraging_ArcPy_in_a_NET_application/000100000m0s000000/)

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple options:

1. Use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) libraries to load Python scripts and call methods directly from C# code. Good article with sample code and detailed explanation for each step found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx).

   or
2. Use [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to execute the script using Python executable

Preferred method would be option 1. It seems to be a more "complete" solution allowing Python script method calls directly from C#, while also allowing exceptions to bubble up. With option 2, you are completely dependent on the separate Python process for error handling and logging.

I hesitated to provide option 2, but it may be required if you can't get the `arcpy` module to play nicely with IronPython.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I did use Process.Start to call python. But the problem is that if I write the full path for workspace and input and output parameters like c:/test/shapefile.shp, inside the python script, it run with no problem. But I would like it used in the arcmap like a button, then I click the button, it will pop out a textbox asking the input and output information for parameters. How can i do that?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ArcMap, but assume you have the flexibility to add some sort of interface that accepts user input. If this is the case, prompt the user for input/output values and pass these as arguments to the Python script. Take a look at `argparse` for defining and working with arguments passed to the Python script. http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

Comment: Thanks anyway. I will take a look at the argparse. I think it will help. Thanks again.