# IronPython cannot import module cv2 (OpenCV)

Tags: c#, opencv, ironpython

First of all, the python code is perfectly working in PyCharm and in command prompt. So, Cv2 module is installed well on my Windows machine.

But when I run by IronPython Script engine, it failed as below.

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named cv2

I setup IronPython engine as below. Note that `site-packages` has `cv2.pyd` file.

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
List<string> pathes = engine.GetSearchPaths().ToList();
pathes.AddRange(new[]
{
    @"C:\Python27\Lib\", @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\"
});
engine.SetSearchPaths(pathes);

dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile("sample.py"); // <- Exception occurred here.
```

I guess `engine.Setup.FileExtensions` has only `.py` file, so that `cv2.pyd` is not recognized. But, I hardly figure out how to add `.pyd` to the setup.

Or, is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did nothing wrong, but `*.pyd` files are just not working for IronPython by default. Just checkout `IronClad` or this so article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1231131/2630261